# @JsonDeserialize annotation do not working

Tags: java, spring-mvc, java-8, json-deserialization

I have the issue when a `@JsonDeserialize` annotation do not working. I've got `400 Bad Request` http code response, when value of the birthday from client contains "12.06.1999", in example.
It is a very strange behavior for me because `@JsonSerialize` annotation works good! But if I use `@DateTimeFormat` annotation instead of `@JsonDeserialize` then all works.

I use java 8 and there is my code:

```
public class Person {
    @JsonProperty("birthday")
    @JsonSerialize(using = DateSerializer.class)
    @JsonDeserialize(using = DateDeserializer.class)
    private LocalDate birthday;

    // other fields, getter and setter, etc.
}

public class DateSerializer extends JsonSerializer<LocalDate> {
    private static final DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd.MM.yyyy");

    @Override
    public void serialize(LocalDate value, JsonGenerator generator, SerializerProvider provider) 
        throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        generator.writeString(formatter.format(value));
    }
}

public class DateDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<LocalDate>{

    @Override
    public LocalDate deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext ctxt)
            throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {

        ObjectCodec oc = jp.getCodec();
        TextNode node = oc.readTree(jp);
        String dateString = node.textValue();

        Instant instant = Instant.parse(dateString);
        LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.ofInstant(instant, ZoneId.systemDefault());
        LocalDate date = LocalDate.of(dateTime.getYear(), dateTime.getMonth(), dateTime.getDayOfMonth());

        return date;
    }
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/savePerson", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public Map<String, Object> savePerson(@ModelAttribute("person") Person person) 
{
    // a some code to save entity
}
```

How should I use `@JsonDeserialize`?

Comment: do you remember how did you solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

log4j's setting helped me a lot: "log4j.category.org.springframework=ALL"

Comment: :| and can you share what it said to u?

Comment: I don't remember because it was a long time ago. But I've got stack trace of exception and resolved it.

Comment: last time i configured log4j on spring boot, caused me issue when i tried to implement it on Tomcat, so i get ride of it :-s, the issue is application enter my Serializer class, but not deserializer class when data returns to server

Comment: Sorry, I really don't remember ((

Answer (score 0):

This may serve your purpose:

```
public class Person {
    @JsonProperty("birthday")
    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern="MM.dd.yyyy")
    private LocalDate birthday;

    // other fields, getter and setter, etc.
}
```

Comment: I still get error: "the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request)"